# Data is not coming in like search in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am not getting data in like search whereas for the same string I am getting data in exact match.My search string is started with a special characters.

Query Strings are :

```
match (n:Details) where n.Name='$$$$Swaraj' return n; //This is working
match (n:Details) where n.Name=~ '(?i).*$$$$Swaraj.*' return n;    //This is not working
```

What is the issue in the query?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `$` is a character with special meaning in the regular expression. I don't know where Neo4j documents the Cypher regular expression syntax (beyond the [few examples in the manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html#_regular_expressions)). A qualified guess is that `$` means 'end-of-line' and if you want to match a literal `$` then you need to escape it. I tried a query with an escaped `$`, but that query failed.

```
MATCH (n:Details) 
WHERE n.Name =~ '(?i).*\$Swaraj' 
RETURN n;
Error: Invalid input '$': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', UTF16 or UTF32 (line 1, column 44 (offset: 43))
"MATCH (n:Details)  WHERE n.Name =~ '(?i).*\$Swaraj'  RETURN n;"
```

If I double escape it, the query works.

```
Query:
MATCH (n:Details)
WHERE n.Name =~ "(?i).*\\$Swaraj"
RETURN n;
```

returns

```
n
(6:Details {Name:"$$$$Swaraj"})
```

**Two notes:**

1) try to find where Cypher's regex syntax is documented or you will be guessing in the dark. Is it perhaps the same as Scala's syntax, since Cypher is written in Scala? If you can't find documentation of Cypher's regex syntax you could try Scala's–at least you'd be guessing in the dusk.

2) The last query, with the doubly escaped `$`, runs and works, but when it displays the executed query together with the result, it shows the query with only one `\`. This is true in the online [console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/dgckqe) and it is true also of the query that is filled in for me to edit or execute–so if I run the query again without changes, it breaks.

```
MATCH (n:Details)
WHERE n.Name =~ '(?i).*\$Swaraj'
RETURN n;
```

This means there is something wrong, not just with your regular expression but with how the query is parsed. This may be a small error only in the web application (I don't have a server instance to try on at the moment) and possibly it has no effect beyond being confusing, but pay attention to it if you have problems with escapes in regexes in the future.

**EDIT**

[This tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_regular_expressions.htm) contains a helpful list of regular expression atoms and examples for Scala, which apparently is the same as for Java.

It also mentions the double escaping:

> Note that every backslash appears twice in the string above. This is because in Java and Scala a single backslash is an escape character in a string literal, not a regular character that shows up in the string. So instead of .\. you need to write .\\. to get a single backslash in the string.

NB I still don't know for a fact that Cypher uses Scala/Java regular expressions. I think it's pretty likely, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

So I think dollar signs are special characters in Cypher regular expressions.  You should use a parameter for any potential dynamic data:

```
match (n:Details) where n.Name =~ {name_expression} return n;
```

The implementation would vary from language to language, but you would then be passing in a parameter.  You'd need to escape the dollar signs and so you'd pass in a string like this:

```
"(?i).*\\$\\$\\$\\$Swaraj.*"
```